# Как посчитать количество заданных словосочетаний?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно, что бы код считал определённые словосочетания, например "you know".

Пример ввода:

```
I called him, you know, 5 times this morning and like, he never answered.
```

Пример вывода: 1

Пробую так:

```
import numpy as np

n = "I called him, you know, 5 times this morning and like, he never answered."
text = str.split(n)
y = np.array(text)
x = np.count_nonzero(y == "you" and "know")
print(x)
```

Comment: а как считать например в этом предложении: "You may know him!" - обратите внимание, что "you" и "know" не стоят рядом и регистр букв не совпадает. Важен ли порядок слов? Как на счет подстрок, "know your customer!"? В общем приведите больше разных примеров, чтобы было понятно когда надо считать пары слов, а когда нет

Comment: Может вы хотите посчитать биграммы? Тогда об этом стоит упомянуть в вопросе...

Comment: нужно именно посчитать кол-во выражений | you know | никаких других

Comment: вы не ответили на другие вопросы из комментария или вас устроит `n.count(" you know ")` ?

Comment: Порядок слов важен, регистр не важен, подстроки не подходят

Comment: count вполне устроит

Comment: не устроит т.к. варианты типа "you knowledge" или "babayou know" тоже посчитаются - а я так понял, что вы их не хотите считать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

text = """I called him, you know, 5 times this morning and like, he never answered.
You know him, right?
What about 'you knowledge' or 'babayou know' - are you guys going to count them as well? ;)
"""

entries = re.findall(r"\byou know\b", text.lower())

res = len(entries) if entries else 0

print(res)
```

результат

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

почему бы не сделать так:

```
text = "I called him, you know, 5 times this morning and like, he never answered."

res = len(text.split("you know")) - 1
```

дешево и очень сердито :)

Comment: Не сделать, ибо вывод 2)

Comment: @Deus, где там вывод `2`? Для его стоит `-1`? Вывод там `1`, а если вообще не содержится `you know`, то вывод будет `0` как и положено - как я понял задачу - ищется именно фраза а не слова во фразе?